# Automatic Deploy Checking Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, deployment

I need to do the automatic deploy to the repository, however it was reported that it is having problems with the jenkins plugin.

At the moment I still don't know where the problem may be

```
Starting Kubernetes deployment
Loading configuration: /home/oracle/.jenkins/jobs/NOTIFICATIONS/jobs/back-notifications-app/branches/develop/workspace/k8s/deployment.yml
ERROR: ERROR: Can't construct a java object for tag:yaml.org,2002:io.kubernetes.client.openapi.models.V1Deployment; exception=Class not found: io.kubernetes.client.openapi.models.V1Deployment
 in 'reader', line 1, column 1:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    ^

hudson.remoting.ProxyException: Can't construct a java object for tag:yaml.org,2002:io.kubernetes.client.openapi.models.V1Deployment; exception=Class not found: io.kubernetes.client.openapi.models.V1Deployment
 in 'reader', line 1, column 1:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    ^

    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor$ConstructYamlObject.construct(Constructor.java:335)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.constructObjectNoCheck(BaseConstructor.java:229)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.constructObject(BaseConstructor.java:219)
    at io.kubernetes.client.util.Yaml$CustomConstructor.constructObject(Yaml.java:337)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.constructDocument(BaseConstructor.java:173)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.getSingleData(BaseConstructor.java:157)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml.loadFromReader(Yaml.java:490)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml.loadAs(Yaml.java:456)
    at io.kubernetes.client.util.Yaml.loadAs(Yaml.java:224)
    at io.kubernetes.client.util.Yaml.modelMapper(Yaml.java:494)
    at io.kubernetes.client.util.Yaml.loadAll(Yaml.java:272)
    at com.microsoft.jenkins.kubernetes.wrapper.KubernetesClientWrapper.apply(KubernetesClientWrapper.java:236)
    at com.microsoft.jenkins.kubernetes.command.DeploymentCommand$DeploymentTask.doCall(DeploymentCommand.java:172)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Helm for Kubernetes, Helm helps you manage Kubernetes applications — Helm Charts help you define, install, and upgrade even the most complex Kubernetes